# Program Execution Sequence Differs. Bounces up and down the code (lines) : The code below is "Code-Sheet" / Worksheet_Change-event, Not a "Module"

Tags: excel, vba

Set the Break point on the first line, then step through (F8), It can be noted that the program does not follow a top-bottom sequence, instead,  Enters IF block, then leaves IF block,  Re-enter IF block after exiting it (After hitting the End Sub).  Could some one explain please ?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Tgt As Range)
  If Not IsNumeric(Tgt.Value) Then
    MsgBox "Numbers Only"
    Tgt.ClearContents
    Tgt.Activate
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Your code is in the Change event, which gets triggered after each time any cell is changed. But the code itself makes a change so it triggers a call to itself.
To ensure the change the change event makes does not trigger the change event :-) , start the change event with:

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

Make sure you add

```
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Just above the End Sub line.

Comment: Hi there,  Thanks for your instant response.